# conditional react return statement

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to avoid the if and probably use a ternary or logical && for below scenario. Looks like react always looks for a an explicit return statement always for any component

```
const reactComp = ({ abc, xyz }) => {
if (something) {
    return (
       <Grid.Container>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Col md="6">
            <Panel title="Title">
               <Text>{mmmm}</Text>
            </Panel>
          </Grid.Col>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid.Container>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a conditional statement directly within the return statement in the component. Here's an example of using a ternary operator. I have included something && something to make sure that something exists before running the conditional.

```
const ReactComp = ({ abc, xyz }) => {
    return (
     // Ternary operator within curly braces 
     // if something exists and if something
     { something && something ?
       // the return the following
       <>
       <Grid.Container>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Col md="6">
            <Panel title="Title">
               <Text>{mmmm}</Text>
            </Panel>
          </Grid.Col>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid.Container>
      </>
     // else
     : 
     // return the following
      <SomethingElse/> // or null 
     // close curly braces
     }
    );
};
```

Comment: had to use the <> fragment just after the return to get this working. now i realise there are so many ways to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

First of React components MUST to start with a big character, in this case `ReactComp`

If react believes it will not return anything, you could solve it by the following. It is also more clean.

```
if (!something) return null
 return (
       <Grid.Container>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Col md="6">
            <Panel title="Title">
               <Text>{mmmm}</Text>
            </Panel>
          </Grid.Col>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid.Container>
    );
  }
```

Comment: @user13021487 Cool! Consider marking the answer with the best solution as the answer by filling the grey "Mark as solution" button and upvoting the answers that helped out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the ternary operator to avoid multiple return statements as shown below:

```
const reactComp = ({ abc, xyz }) => (
  something ? (
    <Grid.Container>
      <Grid.Row>
        <Grid.Col md="6">
          <Panel title="Title">
            <Text>{mmmm}</Text>
          </Panel>
        </Grid.Col>
      </Grid.Row>
    </Grid.Container>
  ) : null
);
```